# Is the Electorate badge voting ratio display format wrong?

Tags: feature-request, badges, electorate-badge

The Electorate badge voting ratio requirement is described in percentage format:

> 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Where as the voting ratio for the progress tracking is in a decimal format:

> Electorate
>      140 question votes (23% done).
>      <sub>Your voting ratio is 0.44 - you are eligible</sub>

For consistency, shouldn't the ratios be expressed in the same format?

Comment: Showing a `%` in the context of a completion-o-meter that isn't related to the `%` complete would be exceptionally confusing, I think.

Comment: Don't dress it up as a completion-o-meter. Maybe something like this: _44% of total votes are on questions - you are eligible_

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything wrong with how it's displayed. The majority of people who are confused about the badge completely miss the `25% or more of total votes are on questions` at the end of the description to begin with. Anyways, it's very easy to figure out that 25% is equivalent to 0.25 and vice versa, so there's not really any reason to change it. It might also conflict with the percentage directly above it. It's nice to see a percentage and a decimal, rather than two percentages.

Comment: *It's nice to see a percentage and a decimal, rather than two percentages.* - Why?  This makes no sense at all to me.  I agree that it's easy enough to figure out, but why?

Comment: @Kevin: Nick explains it in the comments. Two percentages is confusing, you expect them both to be completion meters, when only one is.

Comment: We all may be smart enough to know that 0.44 is equivalent to 44%, but not everybody is that comfortable around fractions. I can't see how a percentage value always infers a completion meter.

Comment: If you know what a percentage *is*, then you immediately understand that 0.44 == 44%. If that identity is *not* obvious to you, then you clearly don't understand what percentages are and what they mean, in which case, the presentation of all this data is completely hopeless. Yes, not everyone is a genius, but try not to be insultingly patronizing. @adr